# "Yours faithfully" or "faithfully yours"? Which one is the correct one?

Tags: phrases

> 1. Yours faithfully
> 2. faithfully yours

I wanna know which one is the correct one?

Comment: Could you clarify your question?  I understand the title, but the rest of the text is hard to understand.

Comment: Both versions were used to close correspondence long ago, but they are pretty archaic.  There's nothing grammatically wrong with either one as a stand-alone phrase.  Either phrase could potentially be used improperly within a sentence, though.

Comment: Also, what kind of correspondence? Such as business or personal. And where?

Comment: I agree. That's something you'd see in a 19th century novel. It is archaic.

Answer (score 3):

Either one is correct, although as fixer1234 mentions they are old-fashioned closing phrases in correspondence.  You might find [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=yours%20faithfully%2C%20faithfully%20yours&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cyours%20faithfully%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfaithfully%20yours%3B%2Cc0) helpful.

As you can see, both were quite common from 1820 to 1920 (with "faithfully yours" being about twice as common as "yours faithfully"), and neither usage has been at all common since the 1940's.

Nowadays, different people sign their emails in different ways.  I generally use "Best Regards," or "Best," with my name two lines down.

You might ind it helpful to study various styles of formal correspondence.  Googling "closing phrases for letters in English" will give you a lot of information.

Comment: I assume that by "Your faithfully" you actually mean "Yours faithfully."  When you say "all usages" I'm not sure what you mean.  Are you saying that google books is not a representative sample of usage?  If so, I'm skeptical and you'll have to convince me.  If not, I don't know what sort of "referenced material" you would like me to provide, that is of more relevance than actual usage, the implied authority of "dictionaries and style manuals" notwithstanding.

Comment: I don't see a link between commonality and correctness. Just because an expression is more common, idiomatic, or trite doesn't make it more correct. The O.P. doesn't ask which phrase is idiomatic; the O.P. asks which is correct. That being the case, numerous variants could be used, including [Yr Most Humble & Obedient Servant](http://wardepartmentpapers.org/blog/?p=1540) – but I've only used that one once in my life (and it got quite a reaction, too).

Answer (score 1):

Yours faithfully is the correct one. It is primarily used in the UK; it is not used in the USA in formal correspondence.

In 1928 H. W. Fowler listed these phrases and their uses:

•   Yours faithfully (to unknown person or business)

•   Yours truly (to slight acquaintance)

•   Yours very truly (ceremonious but cordial)

•   Yours sincerely (in invitations and friendly but not intimate letters)

**Oxford Handbook of Commercial Correspondence**

**Complimentary close**

•   If the letter begins Dear Sir, Dear Sirs, Dear Madam, or Dear Sir or Madam, the complementary close should be “Yours faithfully”.

•   If the letter begins  with a personal name, e.g Dear Mr James, Dear Mrs Robinson, or Dear Ms Jasmin, it would be “Yours sincerely”.

•   A letter to someone you know well may lose with the more informal “Best wishes”.